# Server keeps resetting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sensors

I have a server that keeps resetting. I installed lm_sensors last time, and discovered it was die to the fan not working, causing the temperature to rise.

Now the problem has returned, and lm_sensors is reporting the fan is not spinning, and also a load of `in1`, `in3` things not working.

```
sysadmin@tesfaserver:~$ sensors
w83627dhg-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:        +1.30 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:          +0.86 V  (min =  +0.76 V, max =  +0.18 V)  ALARM
AVCC:         +3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:        +3.39 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:          +1.70 V  (min =  +1.38 V, max =  +1.50 V)  ALARM
in5:          +1.74 V  (min =  +0.99 V, max =  +1.65 V)  ALARM
in6:          +1.86 V  (min =  +1.95 V, max =  +0.30 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.49 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:         +3.31 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.30 V)  ALARM
fan1:           0 RPM  (min = 1562 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan2:           0 RPM  (min = 1687 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =  727 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =  878 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
fan5:           0 RPM  (min =  811 RPM, div = 32)  ALARM
temp1:        +21.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, hyst = +114.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +46.5°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
cpu0_vid:    +0.000 V
intrusion0:  ALARM

sysadmin@tesfaserver:~$
```

Can anyone tell me what the `in1` and `in2` etc are?
What is the consequence of them having an alarm?
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage values being displayed cannot be interpreted correctly without knowing what CPU and motherboard you're using, whether you've overclocked the CPU, etc. The lm_sensors default values which trigger these alarms clearly make absolutely no sense, so you can ignore them.

As for the fans, the most likely problem is that they simply aren't plugged in. To be able to monitor them, the fans must have a 3-pin or 4-pin connector that plugs into a fan connector on your motherboard, and you must actually have the fan plugged into it.

Finally, running a server on a desktop motherboard, such as you're doing, is not guaranteed to be reliable.

Comment: Thanks, that all seems spot on. Re: using desktop motherboard for server, I know it is not as good as server hardware. The computer gets switched off outside of office hours. How much risk is there on the hardware, and what other issues can be anticipated (maybe compatibility etc...). It would be great if you could point me to a resource that explains the issue, as it would help me to convince the clients to spend some money on real server kit. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: Advantage of real servers are 1) That they often come with same day or 4 hour replacement guarantees. 2) They fail less often.  3) they are not all that much more expensive and you often can make a good case of the cost of "server down time" vs "extra cost for proper hardware". Ofc that also depends on what the server is doing, and how much of the office actually uses it.